# Wordpress content through php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Can someone please give me a hello world example for placing text in a wordpress content page through a custom php plugin?
I have been doing it through creating pages with a div id (through wp-admin) and loading content through extensive amounts AJAX/Javascript into that same id. I want to learn how to do this server side. ( It would make my life soooo much easier )

Comment: accept some answers and more people will help you

Comment: What about accepting some answers? Just click the V-shaped mark next to the answer you choose to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use a plugin? Placing shorcodes in the `functions.php` file is the easiest route.

**Example**

In your `functions.php` file

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'class' => 'caption',
      ), $atts ) );

   return '<span class="' . esc_attr($class) . '">' . $content . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode('caption', 'caption_shortcode');
```

In your blog post

> [caption class="headline"]My Text[/caption]

The above would output. If your output is static, this would be the best way to go.

```
<span class="caption">My Text</span>
```

If you're sure you want to make it into a plugin, you can do that too. Simply putting this code in a file and putting it into your plugins directory will work. **Make sure that you use the proper standards when defining the plugins** (see link below).

The last link has both mentioned in the blog post and has a nice plugin that you can use for your own needs. That blog post explains how you can use the shortcodes in widgets as well.

**Links**

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/02/mastering-wordpress-shortcodes/
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
- http://aaron.jorb.in/blog/2010/02/wordpress-shortcodes-a-how-to-by-example/

Comment: This might be exactly what I was asking for. I will check it out this weekend and mark it accepted if it works as expected.

Comment: I don't think you could have provided better links and a better example. This worked exactly how I wanted it to work. You are the man!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Exec-PHP plug-in: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/

Comment: This looks like a possible solution. However I would really like to be able to place content within my plugin libraries instead of inside the wysiwyg editor.